# How can I find the maximum of a 'count' ed field in MS Access' design view?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table where I have "counted" the number of times each entity occurs. I need the find the maximum number of occurrence.

I have unsuccessfully tried to use an aggregate max count expression.

I am only allowed to use Design View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the Maximum number of occurrence, just the number. Then you can use a SubQuery, something like.

```
SELECT 
    Max(CountOfID) As MaxCount 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            Count(tableName.ID) AS CountOfID
        FROM 
            tableName
        GROUP BY 
            tableName.ID
    );
```

The SubQuery will return the `Count` of each ID, then the Main Query gets the `Max` of the `Count`.